# permanentredirect s3 for unspecified endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, ckeditor

I'm experimenting with s3 but im running into a permission problem (i think).

Output:

```
 AWS::S3::PermanentRedirect in CkeditorController#create

The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

I'm using ckeditor. My Ckeditor::Picture class includes this:

```
  has_attached_file :data,
  :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
  :storage => :s3,
  :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension"

  validates_attachment_size :data, :less_than=>2.megabytes
```

In the s3.yml, ive got:

```
access_key_id: "key"
secret_access_key: "key"
bucket: "name"
AWS_CALLING_FORMAT: SUBDOMAIN
```

What am I missing? thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your bucket is not in US Standard zone. Have you tried to add "AWS_CALLING_FORMAT: SUBDOMAIN" to your .yml file? The request should be pointed then to the endpoint corresponding with the region of your bucket.

Comment: thanks for your answer. My bucket is in Europe yes. I tried to create a us bucket & it worked flawlessly. However, I tried to put ur aws_calling_format i and it still didnt work. Ive updated my s3.yml as you can see in my updated question. It's like this no?

Comment: I guess you need to replace SUBDOMAIN with appropriate subdomain for ex: for Asia Pacific: 
AWS_CALLING_FORMAT: s3-website-ap-southeast-1
But it's still not working for me!

Answer (score 8):

With `paperclip` version 3.1.4, simply adding a `s3_host_name` key to my `s3.yml` file worked:

```
development:
  bucket: 'bucket.name'
  access_key_id: 'xxx'
  secret_access_key: 'xxx'
  s3_host_name: 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use default endpoint like following code.

```
s3_credentials: {
     access_key_id: AWS_CONFIG['access_key_id'],
     secret_access_key: AWS_CONFIG['secret_access_key'],
     bucket: AWS_CONFIG['bucket'],
},
s3_host_name: 's3.amazonaws.com',
s3_endpoint: 's3.amazonaws.com',
storage: :s3,
s3_headers:     { "Cache-Control" => "max-age=31557600" },
s3_protocol:    "https",
bucket:         AWS_CONFIG['bucket'],
:url =>':s3_domain_url',
:path => '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
default_url:   "/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
default_style: "medium"
```