# Development error using paperclip and Amazon s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have my app running on heroku and have configured to save all assets uploaded to a bucket using Amazon s3.That all works fine. So when i tried to upload an image locally (development) i get the following error

```
AWS::S3::Errors::PermanentRedirect in RecipesController#update 
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

My update action

```
 def update
 @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])

 if @recipe.update_attributes(params[:recipe])
  redirect_to my_recipes_path, :notice => "Successfully updated recipe"
 else 
 render :action => 'edit'

end
end
```

Though after some reading it appears it is because I am using a bucket in the EU (not the default US one)

I have two buckets, one for development and one for production. and have created a s3.yml file to hold the credentials, though I think it would be better to use ENV variables, I use Ubuntu and I could update my .bashrc file? not to sure on that one.. Anyway my s3.yml file (actual keys removed for security obviosuly)

```
development:
access_key_id: KEY
secret_access_key: KEY
bucket: assets.recipesappdev

production:
access_key_id: KEY
secret_access_key: KEY
bucket: assets.recipesapp
```

and my recipe model config

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
:styles => { :myrecipes => "260x180#", :showrecipe => "600x300#", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
 :storage => :s3,
 :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
  :path => "/images/:id/:style.:extension"
```

Has anyone got a fix for this, I have tried this for example http://www.conandalton.net/2011/02/paperclip-s3-and-european-buckets.html but that doesnt work, though my initializer may be wrong, i tried configuring to suit my app

```
  Paperclip.interpolates(:s3_eu_url) { |assets, style|
 "#{assets.s3_protocol}://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/#{assets.recipesappdev}  /#{assets.path(style).gsub(%r{^/}, "")}"
   }
```

Comment: There's an explanation of the issue here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3#international-users-additional-configuration

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to set the `url` option on `has_attached_file` to `":s3_domain_url"`. (Don't forgot to surround with quotes.)

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
                  :styles => { :myrecipes => "260x180#", :showrecipe => "600x300#", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
                  :storage => :s3,
                  :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                  :path => "/images/:id/:style.:extension",
                  :url => ":s3_domain_url"
```

See the RDoc for [`Paperclip::Storage::S3`](http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3).

Comment: Wish I knew more specifics, but I remember reading something about needing to use `s3_domain_url` if you're using an S3 server in Europe. Glad my guess was correct and that you can get on with your life!

Comment: If anyone else uses this answer you have to define the path otherwise you will recieve an "infinite-interpolation" error. Thanks for the answer Chris.

Answer (score 6):

For the ones, like me, the `url` solution is not working try to set the `s3_host_name` option:

```
:s3_host_name => "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
```

Looks like the european nodes have this issue.

*Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835681/permanentredirect-s3-for-unspecified-endpoint)*

Comment: I was on US, and this still helped me. Thanks!